# A function which is not equal almost everywhere (wrt Lebesgue measure) to a continuous function and not almost everywhere continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, almost-everywhere

I know a function which is not equal a.e to a continuous function is the step function or the characteristic of any interval and I also know the Dirichlet function is not an a.e continuous function but I want an example of a function with both properties.

Comment: Characteristic function of a fat Cantor set.

Answer (score 2):

Choose any 'highly' discontinuous function, like nowhere continuous functions. Examples include [Conway's base-13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) and [real additive functions that are not linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation#Existence_of_nonlinear_solutions_over_the_real_numbers).

---

If you would like a more complete answer, [this (freely accessible) paper](https://lematematiche.dmi.unict.it/index.php/lematematiche/article/view/198)  fully characterizes functions $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ which are almost everywhere equal to some continuous function.

> Let $I_r(z)=\{x\in\mathbb R\,;\,|x-z|<r\}$.
>   We say that $f$ has a *$C$-limit $l$ at $x$* if
>
> $$\forall \epsilon>0,\,\exists\delta>0,\quad
> \mu\Big(I_\delta(x)\cap f^{-1}\big(\mathbb R\setminus I_\epsilon(l)\big)\Big)=0.$$
>
> Let $\mathscr C_f$ be the set of $x\in\mathbb R$ at which $f$ admits some $C$-limit.
>   Then $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is almost everywhere equal to some continuous function if and only if $\mathscr C_f=\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I guess there are no simple examples. Any idea on how to prove they are not equal a.e to a continuous function?

Comment: "Most" functions are nowhere continuous and probably have no noteworthy properties. These examples are just involved because, in addition to being nowhere continuous, they carry other properties (like being Darboux or being additive).$${}$$

A continuous function is measurable. If $f$ is measurable and $g=f$ a.e., then $g$ is also measurable (why?). Do you think you can take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

Proposition: If $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is continuous and not constant then $\{x:0\ne g(x)\ne 1\}$ is not Lebesgue-null. Proof: $g^{-1}(\Bbb R \setminus \{0,1\})$ is open so if it is not empty it is not Lebesgue-null. But if it is empty then $g$ is a continuous real function that takes values only in $\{0,1\},$ which requires $g$ to be constant.

For $S\subset \Bbb R$ let $\chi_S:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ denote  the characteristic (indicator) function of $S.$

Corollary to the Proposition: If $S\subset \Bbb R$ and $S$ is not Lebesgue-measurable  and if $g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continuous then $\neg (g=\chi_S\; a.e.).$ ....Proof of Corollary:

(i). If $g$ is not constant then   $\{x:g(x)\ne \chi_S(x)\}\supset \{x:0\ne x\ne 1\},$ which, by the Proposition, is  not  Lebesgue-null.

(ii). If $g=1$ or if $g=0$ then $\{x:g(x)\ne \chi_S(x)\}\in \{S,\Bbb R \setminus S\}$ and neither $S$ nor $\Bbb R \setminus S$  is  Lebesgue-null as neither is  Lebesgue-measurable.

There is an elementary example of a non-Lebesgue $S\subset \Bbb R$ which is dense and co-dense. Then $\chi_S$ is nowhere continuous (because  $S$ and $\Bbb R \setminus S$ are both dense), and by the above Corollary, $\neg (\chi_S=g \;a.e.)$ for any continuous $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$.

Comment: On the other hand if you want a measurable function see Daniel Fischer's comment to the Q